# How are syllables broken up in Ukrainian?

Tags: software, syllables

Some languages, [such as Spanish](http://lessonplanspage.com/ladivisionofsyllablesinspanish612-htm/), have specific rules for how to form syllables.

I'm writing an app and one of the things I need to do is to find a syllable count of some Ukrainian text. I remember reading that Ukrainian does not have diphthongs so I imagine that it would be close to the number of vowels, but as I understand in Ukrainian consonants can sometimes forms their own syllables. Under what circumstances does this happen?

Comment: I don’t remember when it can be, І guess it is only for particle like _в_ (in), _й_ (and), [_б_](/a/150/585) (_kinda_ would), _з_ (with), _ж_ (_kinda_ but-but). But are they really sillables? I doubt, but I do not have source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I read your question as you are *not* asking about the whole set of verbalized rules, but you need a software to process it instead. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

---

In most languages, including Ukrainian, **hyphenation** occurs on the boundaries between syllables. In other words, the problem of **syllabification** is equivalent to the problem of **hyphenation**.

Unless you are an avid developer, linguist, and NLP/ML professional, you don't need developing your own tool for doing that. Take an existing one. A bonus feature is that **both algorithms and dictionaries evolve**, and you sooner or later get free updates.

There are lots of free/open-source **hyphenation libraries** existing, including those for Mozilla Firefox, OpenOffice, and others. They are pretty much complicated, and it will take a lot of your effort to develop something similar.

One of such tools is [Myspell Hyphenator](http://lingucomponent.openoffice.org/hyphenator.html).

Since nobody can know *all* languages, the hyphenation libraries use their meta-language for dictionary definitions. Other people who are familiar with individual languages, develop the dictionaries.

One of such dictionaries is [Великий електронний словник української мови (ВЕСУМ)](https://github.com/brown-uk/dict_uk) distributed under the terms of By-NC-SAA 4.0 license.

[Here's an example](https://github.com/brown-uk/dict_uk/blob/master/distr/openoffice.org/hyphen/hyph_uk_UA.dic) how the dictionary looks like.

Comment: I would've also accepted a set of verbalized rules since I do have an interest in linguistics, but thank you for your thorough answer! I'll have to do a bit more research into hyphenation before I come back (my app is commercial so the ВЕСУМ wouldn't be ideal)

Comment: Do you know where I might be able to find a machine-readable stress/pronunciation dictionary for Ukrainian? Kinda like the CMU dictionary for English. (Should this be a separate question or is it off-topic?)

Comment: @FracturedRetina, stress patterns is a quite different problem (than syllabification), so I think it could be a separate question. I'd also like to know if such tools exist.